# Correct way to import mocked functions from node modules using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm learning Jest and it seems like this should be so simple, but I'm missing the forest for the trees and would appreciate some guidance.

I am using Jest to test Express routes.  The express routes are in the file `/routes/index.js` and they each call a corresponding logic function in a file `/logic/index.js`.  `routes` and `logic` directories are next to each other, at the same level.

I then put a `__mocks__` directory inside of directory `logic` and create a `index.js` file inside `__mocks__`

```
//  logic/__mocks__/index.js
import clients from '../../../data/clients'

export const getUserForUserName =  (name) => {
 return Promise.resolve(()=> clients.filter(client => client.name === name) )
}
```

I create a `__tests__` directory inside `routes` and put an `index.js` file inside it

```
// routes/__tests_/index.js
jest.mock("../../logic");
import {getUserForUserName} from "../../logic/__mocks__"


    it("gets correct data for user name", async () => {
  const data = await getUserForUserName("Ines");
  expect(data).toEqual([{"email": "inesblankenship@quotezart.com", "id": "4a0573eb-56d0-45d5-ab36-bebf33c5eb36", "name": "Ines", "role": "admin"}]);
});
```

Is this the correct way to set this up?  The line

```
import {getUserForUserName} from "../../logic/__mocks__"
```

seems so 'hardwired' to me, but I suppose it has to be this way.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to import the file without using `__mocks__` at all in the path name. Jest will handle resolving to use your mock instead of the actual function.

For example:

```
// routes/__tests_/index.js
jest.mock("../../logic");
import {getUserForUserName} from "../../logic"
```

This is in essence the same as the example with "banana" in the docs.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it didn't work for me.  I'll investigate further…